# Structure ngrx using angularfire2 with stateChanges ()

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, ngrx

Can I have a collection of entities within an entity using [Ngrx - Entity Adapter](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter)?

I need to create a collection of entities within an entity, how can I do this using NgRx with Cloud Firestore?

I know I could create an array inside the Pizza document, but I want to do this using the scalability of the Cloud Firestore because I want to perform functions with dynamic Cloud Functions.

I want something like what is in this [AngularFire2 State Changex With Ngrx](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/state-changes-angularfire2-with-ngrx/) lesson, but I want to have for each Pizza the toppings that should stay within the Pizzas state in each entity.

**Cloud Firestore Paths:**

**PathRefPizzas**: `pizzas/{pizaId}`;

**PathRefToppings**: `pizzas/{pizaId}/toppings/{toppingId}`;

```
export function pizzasReducer(
    state: PizzaState = initialState,
    action: ActionPizza) {

switch (action.type) {

    case actionsPizza.PIZZA_ADDED: {
        return unidadeAdapter.addOne(action.payload, state)
    };

    case actionsPizza.PIZZA_MODIFIED:
        return pizzaAdapter.updateOne({
            id: action.payload.id,
            changes: action.payload
        }, state)

    case actionsPizza.PIZZA_REMOVED:
        return pizzaAdapter.removeOne(action.payload.id, state)

    case actionsPizza.TOPPING_ADDED: {
        // Here I need to add Toppings inside a Pizza entity in which it belongs.
        return toppingsAdapter.addOne(action.payload, state);
    }

    default:
        return state;
}
```

The data in the state should be as follows.

```
pizzas: {
    ids: [...]
    entities: [
        {'pizza1': {id: 'pizza1, name: 'Pizza 1', toppings: [...]},
        {'pizza2': {id: 'pizza2, name: 'Pizza 2', toppings: [...]}
        {'pizza3': {id: 'pizza3, name: 'Pizza 3', toppings: [...]}
        {'pizza4': {id: 'pizza4, name: 'Pizza 4', toppings: [...]}
        {'pizza5': {id: 'pizza5, name: 'Pizza 5', toppings: [...]}
    ];
}
```

How would I do this using ngrx state management? If anyone can help me how can I do this, I will be very grateful for this, it is very important for me !!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but it's not a good practice to do that. With state management (redux pattern) and hence `ngrx`, you should normalize your store.

[Recommend read for Redux pattern](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape).

It means, in your case, you should have a dedicated `ngrx entity` for your `Topping` model.

Your store should looks like below:

```
state {
  pizzas: {
    ids: [...]
    entities: [
        {'pizza1': {id: 'pizza1, name: 'Pizza 1', ...},
        {'pizza2': {id: 'pizza2, name: 'Pizza 2', ...},    
    ];
  },
  toppings: {
    ids: [...]
    entities: [
        {'topping1': {id: 'topping1, pizzaId: 'pizza1', name: 'Topping 1', ...},
        {'topping2': {id: 'topping2, pizzaId: 'pizza1', name: 'Topping 2', ...},    
    ];
  }
}
```

Then via `selectors` you will be able to retrieve the `topppings` list for the selected `pizza` :

```
getToppings = createSelector(getSelectedPizzaId, getAllToppings, (state, selectedPizzaId, allToppings) => {
  return allToppings.filter(topping => topping.pizzaId === selectedPizzaId)
});
```

For better performance, you could also consider creating a optional third `entity` dedicated to relationship between `pizza` and `toppings`:

```
store {
  ...
  pizzaToppingIds {
    entities: [
      {'pizza1': { toppingIds: ['topping1', 'topping2']},
      {'pizza2': { toppingIds: ['topping3', 'topping4']},    
    ];
  }
}
```

In this case, `selector` should be: (simplified, some tests are missing...)

```
getToppings = createSelector(getSelectedPizzaId, getPizzaToppingEntities, getToppingEntities, (state, selectedPizzaId, pizzaToppingEntities, toppingEntities) => {
  return pizzaToppingEntities[selectedPizzaId].toppingIds
    .map(id => toppingEntities[id];
});
```

If you really want to go again this common pattern and good practice, you can always to consider updating `pizza` entity each time a `topping` is added. But it will update the entire `entity`.

One again, it will work but `state management` architecture of your app will lose a part of its interest and its power.